# Adding a separator line alongside a heading

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

[image]

This i what i try to achieve. Thing is i want it to go with a heading if possible and occupy te rest of the available space from its container.

```
<div class="col-xs-12">
    <h4>Image Boxes <span class="sep"></span></h4>
</div>
```

This is the html

```
h4 .sep{
    height:1px;
    width: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    background: grey;
}
```

And this the CSS

I am using the bootstrap framework

Comment: how do i add a separating line alongside a heading like in that picture

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do something like this

```
.col-xs-12{
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
}

h4{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 20%;
    display: inline-block;
}

.sep{
   height: 1px;
   width: 80%;
   display: inline-block;
   background: grey;
   vertical-align: middle;
}
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/32UAJ/)

**UPDATE**

Ok you can do it like this then

[NEW FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/32UAJ/1/)

```
.col-xs-12 {
   overflow: hidden; /* clear the float */
   background: #f5f5f5; 
}

h4 {
   width: 100px;
   float: left;
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
}


.sep {
   overflow: hidden;
}

span{
  height: 1px;
  display: inline-block;
  background: grey;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 100%;    
}
```

**UPDATE**

The text is going to collapse unless you set a width to contain it so if you need this to be dynamic just use jquery and determine the width of the h4 and set it to be that width. That way it will always adjust:

```
var naturalWidth = $("h4").width();
$("h4").css({"width":naturalWidth+"px"});
```

[NEWEST FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/32UAJ/2/)

Comment: i understand what you suggest but i need the text to say on one line no matter how small the container gets

Comment: @morgred make sure to select an answer.