# how to add a line alongside a heading

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

[image]

I am trying to achieve something like this. IMPORTANT! The separating line must occupy the rest of what is available in the containing heading.  No, fixed widths won't do for either one. I need it to look like this no matter how big or small the text in it is. I am using twitter Bootstrap 3 as framework

```
<h4>Events With Thumbnail <span class="h-sep"> </span> </h4>

.h-sep{
    display: inline-block;
    line-height:22px;
    height:1px;
    background-color: grey;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I already gave you the answer to this. The text is going to collapse unless you set a width to contain it so if you need this to be dynamic just use jquery and determine the width of the h4 and set it to be that width. That way it will always adjust:

```
var naturalWidth = $("h4").width();
$("h4").css({"width":naturalWidth+"px"});
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/32UAJ/2/)

Comment: JavaScript isn't the answer to such a trivial problem. I've a hunch this can be done in CSS.

Comment: @rvighne this isnt a trivial problem. And i already gave morged the answer using css, the problem is there cant be fixed widths but the text and/or line cant drop to a different line when you resize the browser

Comment: here was the original post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21198691/adding-a-separator-line-alongside-a-heading

Comment: Well, now I'm marking this question duplicate. You may want to move this answer to the original question.

Comment: sounds good, ill add it

Comment: yea, i figured this is rather tricky. if it were trivial i should have figured it by now. jquery is a rather simple and good solution in this case i believe. what does the "px" represent in your code?

Comment: @morgred CSS pixel units.

Comment: yes, that variable is just an integer so you have to include it will "px" so that it outputs as `100px` in the css